# How to insert multiple records 100 times in mysql query with integer and string data in it using loop concept?

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I want to increase `intemployeeID`, `employeeID`, and `buddyname` suffixes from a given number.
I want to do this about 100 times, using a loop for mysql for about 100 employees.
Basically, I need to populate 100 records, where the above fields increase sequentially from a given initial number.

```
  declare @count int;
    set @count = 100;

    while @count <= 100 
    begin

    insert into Employees(intEmployeeID, employeeID, firstName, lastName, deletedFlag, intCompanyID, createTime, modTime) values
    (1,'name1','firstname','lastname',0,-1,unix_timestamp(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

    insert into EmployeeBuddyNames (intEmployeeID, buddyName, networkID, enabledFlag, deletedFlag, intCompanyID, createTime, modTime, APIAuthTime) values
    (1,'id=123',24,1,0,-1,unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp());
end
```

which should increase my few field like below.
.
.
. into this 1,2,3...etc name1, name2, name3...etc.. id=123, id=124, id=125..etc

```
insert into Employees(intEmployeeID, employeeID, firstName, lastName, deletedFlag, intCompanyID, createTime, modTime) values
(2,'name2','firstname','lastname',0,-1,unix_timestamp(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

insert into EmployeeBuddyNames (intEmployeeID, buddyName, networkID, enabledFlag, deletedFlag, intCompanyID, createTime, modTime, APIAuthTime) values
(2,'id=124',24,1,0,-1,unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp());
```

etc till 100 times...

Comment: The answer will not be found in SQL and has nothing to do with MySQL or any other database. The answer is in the code *calling* the database: the is solved using app code. Since you have given no info about how the calls are being made, we can’t help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your rows' unique identifier columns should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`. This way you don't need to worry about trying to keep track of which ID comes next (for those columns) and when you do your `INSERT` you can just omit these columns because they are unnecessary.

Then for the other columns that you want to concatenate a string with an auto-incrementing integer, you can base this off of the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` plus an integer:

```
insert into Employees (
    employeeID,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    deletedFlag,
    intCompanyID,
    createTime,
    modTime
)
values (
    CONCAT('name1', LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1),
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    0,
    -1,
    unix_timestamp(),
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
);

insert into EmployeeBuddyNames (
    buddyName, 
    networkID, 
    enabledFlag, 
    deletedFlag, 
    intCompanyID, 
    createTime, 
    modTime, 
    APIAuthTime
)
values (
    CONCAT('id=', LAST_INSERT_ID() + 123)
    24,
    1,
    0,
    -1,
    unix_timestamp(), 
    unix_timestamp(),
    unix_timestamp()
);
```

You can then execute these queries as many times as you like without having to worry about manually modifying values.

[See it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4cf6/1)

Also I recommend you rename `employeeID` to something like `username`. Columns with "id" in their name should be numeric and either be the unique identifier for that row or a foreign key. Otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: i need to manually populate above data using this query for 100 employees. so auto increment would not make sense

Comment: What data do you need to manually populate? You didn't mention anything about that in the question. You said it needs to be done in a loop. Please clarify.

Comment: im looking for using loop concept or any better approach.  where i need to range intemployeeid from last highest value from db, instead im trying to give it manually the diff range if 1,2,3 already exist

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to say. Please provide examples.

Comment: declare initialize changing variables;
while (condition) //100 times
{
queries
}

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me understand what your logic is and how you plan on "manually populating" values when in a while loop.

Comment: It's not clear to me or to Bohemian, who closed this question.

Comment: im sorry about it, seems you are stuck with your concepts even after i have updated the question.